# how to make buttons stay the same size in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a dynamic table whose rows have buttons.
I am interested in designing the table as follows:

1. The buttons will fill in exactly the `td` where they are.
2. The buttons will remain the same size so they will continue to fill in the `td` where they are **even when I add new buttons**

I tried several methods, but nothing worked and Lar was able to bring about the fulfillment of the two conditions I set out above.
Below is the code. help would be very appreciated:

```js
const animals = [{
    "animalId": "1",
    "animalName": "elephent",
    "cageNum": "231",
    "legsNum": "4",
    "CandidatesForDeletion": false
    },
    {
        "animalId": "2",
        "animalName": "tiger",
        "cageNum": "324",
        "legsNum": "56.00",
        "CandidatesForDeletion": false
    },
    {
        "animalId": "3",
        "animalName": "wolf",
        "cageNum": "414",
        "legsNum": "210.40",
        "CandidatesForDeletion": false
    }
]

let tableBody = '<table id="table"><tr class="tr tr1"><td class="td1">animal Id</td><td class="td1">animal name</td><td class="td1">cage Number</td><td class="td1">legs Number</td><td class="td1">delete</td></tr>';

animals.forEach(function(d) {
    tableBody += '<tr class="tr tr2""><td class="td2">' + d.animalId + '</td><td class="td2">' + d.animalName + '</td><td class="td2">' + d.cageNum + '</td><td class = "td2">' + d.legsNum + '</td><td class="td2 buttons">Button</td></tr>';
});

function CreateTableFromJSON() {
    $('#showData').html(tableBody);
}

function creatNewRow () {
tableBody += '<tr class="tr tr2""><td class="td2">' + "newRow" + '</td><td class="td2">' + "newRow" + '</td><td class="td2">' + "newRow" + '</td><td class = "td2">' + "newRow" + '</td><td class="td2 buttons">Button</td></tr>';
}
```

```css
#table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 90%;
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

.tr {

    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 17%;
}

.tr1 {
    background: #16A1E7;
    height: 80px;
}

.tr2 {
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: 0.4s;
    height: 80px;
     
}

.td1 {
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 17%;
}

.td2 {
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 17%;
    
     }

.buttons {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    display: block;
   
}


.buttons:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()">Show table</button>
<button onclick="creatNewRow()">New Row</button>
<p id="showData"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.buttons {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
```

I removed unnecessary code such as `align-items: center;` `justify-items: center;`

> justify-items property is not implemented in the flexbox (display:
> flex;)

I removed: `display: block;` which is the default value by the browser you don't need to change it unless you made some changes in the parents. and finally the `position: absolute;` you could have added a `position: relative` to the container(parent) . but in your case, you didn't need a position absolute so better remove it.

```
 /* position: absolute; */
```

then I changed the display to flex so I can control the element content. you can either use display: gird or flex, but I found that flex work better in this case.

```
         /*change display to flex*/ 
         display: flex;
         /*align as you like*/ 
         align-items: center; 
         justify-content: center;
    }
```

finally your code look something like this:

```
.buttons {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 3px;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center; 
            justify-content: center;
        }

 .buttons img{
        /*add max-width:100%; to the image to limit its size from going bigger than the table.*/
           max-width:100%;
        /*customize your image size here*/
           height:100%;
        /*to control the width of the cell*/
           margin: auto -30px;
    }
```

here is your code:
https://codepen.io/weaksou/pen/ExvPqPR